# Every element in a non-principal filter is infinite

Tags: general-topology, filters

I have to prove that if $\mathcal{F}$ is a non-principal filter then $\forall F \in \mathcal{F}$,
$F$ is an infinite set, I tried by the contrapositive and absurdum but couln't get any result using just the definition of a filter so any hint will be useful.
Thanks

Comment: Hint: If $F\in\mathcal{F}$ is finite and $\mathcal{F}$ is non-principal, then what does that tell you about subsets of $F$? Can it happen, that $\mathcal{F}$ contains no subsets of $F$?

Comment: Note that for all $x$, $\{x\} \notin \mathcal{F}$ and thus $\{x\}^c \in \mathcal{F}$. Therefore, if $F = \{x_1, \ldots, x_n\}$, then $F^c = \{x_1\}^c \cap \cdots \cap \{x_n\}^c \in \mathcal{F}$ and therefore $F \notin \mathcal{F}$.

Comment: Thanks @MarkSaving but I cannot use that propertie because I have that a filter $\mathcal{F}$ is non-principal iff $\cap  \mathcal{F} = \emptyset$ while the propertie you mention is about ultra-filters

Comment: See my answer that doesn’t use that property at all.

Comment: Thanks  for your answer @HennoBrandsma, I could finally understand the proposition.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Suppose that $A \in \mathcal{F}$ where $A$ is finite. Enumerate $A = \{a_1,...,a_n\}$. Prove that either $\{a_{1}\} \in \mathcal{F}$ or $A - \{a_{1}\} \in \mathcal{F}$. If $\{a_{1}\}$ is in $\mathcal{F}$, you are done. If not, repeat with $A - \{a_{1}\}$.

Answer (score 2):

If $A \in \mathcal{F}$ is finite consider the set of cardinalities

$$\{|A \cap F|: F \in \mathcal{F}\}$$

This has a minimum $m \in \Bbb N$ where $0 < m \le |A|$, assumed for $F_0 \in \mathcal{F}$. The filter axioms then tell us that

$$\mathcal{F} = \{B\mid A \cap F_0 \subseteq B\}$$

using the minimality of $|A \cap F_0|$ as well.

So $\mathcal F$ is principal (generated by $A \cap F_0$) and $\bigcap \mathcal F = A \cap F_0 \neq \emptyset$.